# How can i store return key to a variable without appearing print function in console screen?

Tags: python, function, return

```
def a():
    print("Hello World!")
    b = 1
    return b

c = a()

print(c)
```

I just want to display 1 in the console window, but the string'Hello world' also appears. How can I fix this?

```
def a(printing):
    if printing == True:
        print("Hello World!")
    b = 1
    return b

c = a(printing = False)

print(c)
```

Thank you very much! I solved this problem with parameter :)

Comment: ... dont' put `print("hello world")` in your function?

Comment: When you use a function elsewhere, i need a print function. So, I want to keep the content inside the function as it is.

Comment: You could add an optional parameter to your function that determined whether it called the `print()` function or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this.

```py
def a(printing=False):
    if printing:
        print("Hello World!")
    b = 1
    return b

c = a()

print(c)

# Print Hello World and 1
print_hello = a(printing=True)

print(print_hello)
```

Alternatively you could nest methods.

```py
def a()
    return 1

def A():
    print("Hello World!")
    return a()

c = a()

print(c)

# To print hello world and 1
print_hello = A()

print(print_hello)
```

You could also have use a variable in the outer scope of the method and set it to True/False before you run the method.

I do not see an obvious way of doing this without some kind of extra variable, parameter or method call.  All 3 of these methods would allow you to call `a()` without any parameters and have it not print `Hello world!`